# Android room inMemoryDatabaseBuilder VS regular database

Tags: android, android-room, in-memory-database

In the documentation
"... Information stored in an in memory database disappears when the process is killed..."
It is not clear to me where the information is stored.
Is the process the same as regular db only that db is deleted at the end of the session.
Or the process is different and the information is stored in some collections and no io operations are performed at all.
I ask because I want to use db queries on the main thread.
Thanks

Comment: "It is not clear to me where the information is stored" -- it is stored in RAM. The details are up to SQLite and have little to do with Android, let alone Room.

Comment: do you have source?

Comment: https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html